# Windows 11 screen timeout - no lock though

Tags: windows-11, lock-screen

I've set the screen on my laptop to turn off after 20 minutes, like in the screenshot. I would expect that this results in a lockscreen, requiring me to enter the password when I return.

[image]

Just now I had a meeting for 90 minutes, and pressing the spacebar was enough to activate the computer, without password. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

1. In settings to go to **Personalization** > **Lock screen** and click
   on **Screen saver** (or open the ***Screen Saver Settings*** by
   searching for **Change screen saver** in the Start Menu.)
2. Set the **Wait** time to the same as you have in the Power settings
3. Check the **On resume display logon screen**
4. Click **OK** (or ***Apply***) to save setting

[image]

Comment: In the power settings, the time can be (and often should be) different for battery and plugged in. This here seems to only allow a single time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Accounts, Sign in Options.

Check the settings there to help ensure you get a sign in screen:

Make sure you are always asked for a password. This has worked for me on my Windows 11 Laptop.

[image: Sign in Options]